# Adding a class based on current day of the week

Tags: jquery, css, class, dynamic

I've got a bunch of tabbed divs on a page for each day of the week, which are being shown/hidden with jQuery when clicked.

The class "first", added manually to whatever tab I want, tells the page which div to show when the user first lands there.

At the moment it is set to the Monday div.

How would I go about setting this up so that jQuery can add the class dynamically to the actual current day's div instead of hard coding it?

Divs are set up like this (with Monday being currently selected):

```
 <div id="sh-MON" class="daily-Sched first">
 <div id="sh-TUE" class="daily-Sched">
 <div id="sh-WED" class="daily-Sched">

 etc
```

I know it's something to do with "eq" and have tried this below but it doesn't work. I can't see how it would either?

```
 $('.daily-Sched:eq(' + new Date().getDay() + ')').addClass('first');
```

Any help greatly apppreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();

n = n > 0 ? n - 1 : 6; // zero is sunday, not monday in javascript

$('.daily-Sched').eq(n).addClass('first');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8GrJy/)